# Error related group by when executing query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1055

Mysql returning following error when i executing query (with Group BY) for getting the result

> Error Code: 1055
>
> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'project.ws_images.wi_id' which is
> not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I want to get result with group by **MONTH**. I have searched about it and found some solution but still facing the issue. I have tried so far

```
SELECT * FROM `ws_images` WHERE wi_type = 'image' GROUP BY MONTH(date_added);
 SELECT * FROM `ws_images` WHERE wi_type = 'image' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%Y%m');
```

Above both queries returning me same error which i have already mentioned. Can someone guide me  where is the issue that i can fix. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me.

[image]

Comment: The use of `select *` with `group by` shows a lack of understanding of SQL.  You should provide both sample data and desired results, because your queries make no sense at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry so highlight my requirement. I need all result group by MONTH

Comment: @Mr.Developer . . . `group by MONTH` doesn't make sense when you want all the other columns.  `group by` is usually used with aggregation functions.

Comment: If you want to group results visually in the output, you should use `ORDER BY` instead and group the results as you like when you build the view. `GROUP BY` in sql does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a group by without aggregation function .. this behavior in mysql 5.7 is not allowed  and you should unset  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`  in `sql_mode`  setting .

You  should esplicitally assign the  columns name you need in select clause  eventually use distinct (without group by)  if you don't need repeated value ..

otherwise you should explicitally assign the  columns  and the aggregation function. Be carefull of assign the column not in aggregation function to group by clause

Comment: Thanks for well explanation

Answer (score 0):

In `mysql`, you should set `sql_mode` without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to do the query you mentioned in op. Or you only can select columns in `group by` clause, and some aggregational columns.